# Meaning of "oh freak"

Tags: meaning

What do people usually mean by saying "oh! freak"? I looked up "freak" in the dictionary. The answer I got is "freak" is used for a person who is obsessed about something (fitness, looks, etc).

Comment: Could you provide some written examples of this? It is hard to say without more context.

Comment: It's likely an inoffensive alternative to "Oh, fuck!".

Comment: It may be a minced oath, or it may be referring to something or someone who is "freaky", like that kid in 9th grade that always dresses Goth.

Comment: Without context, it could simply be "Oh, that freaked me."

Answer (score 21):

**Please note that this answer is about, and as a result contains, swear words. Parental discretion is advised.**

They're using the word "freak" as a euphemism, a sort of pseudo-swear. In polite conversation, it's generally not acceptable to use profanity. To get around this, there are many substitutes that people use which are somewhat similar in sound but are considered acceptable.

For example, instead of using the word "fuck", some people say "frik", "frig", or as you have heard, "freak". A replacement for "damn" is "darn". "Shit" may become "shucks", and "heck" is used for "hell".

Many religious people use "gosh" in place of "God", although this is an example of a different definition of profane.

Comment: Such euphemisms for taboo terms go by the moniker *minced oaths*.

Comment: But yet I've never seen "crap" changed (outside of one really bad pun). I wonder why that is.

Comment: @tox123- "*crap*" is not a swear word.  It ***is*** the replacement for *shit*.

Comment: @tox123 Not only is "crap" itself a replacement, but it *does* have an even milder replacement (often "crikey" is used).

Comment: "Crikey" is a euphemism for Christ, not for crap.

Comment: Believe it or not, I've heard "oh crab cakes" as a replacement for "oh crap", used by an unusually pious individual, the son of a priest.

Comment: People trying to stop swearing around children or their bosses or whatever even tend to use stranger words. I know at least two which have replaced all swear words with "sugar".

Comment: @cdaddr probably "Oh cra--- er, er, b cakes"

Comment: I've also frequently heard "Oh, fudge!" for the list of "fuck" euphemisms.

Comment: @cdaddr Heck that "crab cakes" shucks is freaking good!

Comment: Considering what "frig" is also commonly used to mean in some circles, *it* might not be minced swearing at all.